# streamplot does not work with matplotlib basemap

Tags: python, vector, matplotlib, stream, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to use streamplot function to plot wind field with basemap, projection `"ortho"`. My test code is mainly based on this example:
[Plotting wind vectors and wind barbs](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html)

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, shiftgrid
from Scientific.IO.NetCDF import NetCDFFile as Dataset

# specify date to plot.
yyyy=1993; mm=03; dd=14; hh=00
date = datetime.datetime(yyyy,mm,dd,hh)
# set OpenDAP server URL.
URLbase="http://nomads.ncdc.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/modeldata/cmd_pgbh/"
URL=URLbase+"%04i/%04i%02i/%04i%02i%02i/pgbh00.gdas.%04i%02i%02i%02i.grb2" %\
         (yyyy,yyyy,mm,yyyy,mm,dd,yyyy,mm,dd,hh)
data = Dataset(URL)
#data = netcdf.netcdf_file(URL)
# read lats,lons
# reverse latitudes so they go from south to north.
latitudes = data.variables['lat'][:][::-1]
longitudes = data.variables['lon'][:].tolist()
# get wind data
uin = data.variables['U-component_of_wind_height_above_ground'][:].squeeze()
vin = data.variables['V-component_of_wind_height_above_ground'][:].squeeze()
# add cyclic points manually (could use addcyclic function)
u = np.zeros((uin.shape[0],uin.shape[1]+1),np.float64)
u[:,0:-1] = uin[::-1]; u[:,-1] = uin[::-1,0]
v = np.zeros((vin.shape[0],vin.shape[1]+1),np.float64)
v[:,0:-1] = vin[::-1]; v[:,-1] = vin[::-1,0]
longitudes.append(360.); longitudes = np.array(longitudes)
# make 2-d grid of lons, lats
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(longitudes,latitudes)
# make orthographic basemap.
m = Basemap(resolution='c',projection='ortho',lat_0=60.,lon_0=-60.)
# create figure, add axes
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(8,10))
ax = fig1.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8])
# define parallels and meridians to draw.
parallels = np.arange(-80.,90,20.)
meridians = np.arange(0.,360.,20.)
# first, shift grid so it goes from -180 to 180 (instead of 0 to 360
# in longitude).  Otherwise, interpolation is messed up.
ugrid,newlons = shiftgrid(180.,u,longitudes,start=False)
vgrid,newlons = shiftgrid(180.,v,longitudes,start=False)
# now plot.
lonn, latt = np.meshgrid(newlons, latitudes)
x, y = m(lonn, latt)
st = plt.streamplot(x, y, ugrid, vgrid, color='r', latlon='True')
# draw coastlines, parallels, meridians.
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=1.5)
m.drawparallels(parallels)
m.drawmeridians(meridians)
# set plot title
ax.set_title('SLP and Wind Vectors '+str(date))
plt.show()
```

After running the code, I got a blank map with a red smear in the lower left corner (please see the figure). After zoom this smear out, I can see the wind stream in a flat projection (not in "ortho" projection) So I guess this is the problem of data projection on the map. I did tried function `transform_vector` but it does not solve the problem [image]Can anybody tell me, what did I do wrong, please! Thank you.

A new map after updating code:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are plotting `lat/lon` coordinates on a map with an orthographic projection. Normally you can fix this by changing your plotting command to:

```
m.streamplot(mapx, mapy, ugrid, vgrid, color='r', latlon=True)
```

But your coordinate arrays don't have the same dimensions, that needs to be fixed as well.

Comment: Thank you @Rutger Kassies. I add two lines of code: `loon,latt = np.meshgrid(newlines,latitudes) x,y = m.(lonn, latt)` and then `m.streamplot(x, y, ugrid, vgrid, color='r', latlon=True)`. Now I got a blank map with a strange line and some messages on screen `packages/numpy/ma/core.py:802: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  return umath.less(x, self.critical_value)`. Please see the update code and new blank map above